# Error: An invalid OpenApi version was detected: '', must be one of 2.x or 3.x

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, serverless, aws-sam

> I am creating a swagger document for AWS SAM, i am using nodejs, i am getting this error, help me to resolve this and also let me know how can i test it locally, how can i run and see swagger ui locally in aws sam.

> this is what i have created swagger.yaml file for swagger configuration

```
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title: "EcoVision Service API"
  description: "EcoVision service apis"
  contact:
    name: "Product Technology - Sourcing team"
    email: "supplierportalsupport@kmart.com.au"
  termsOfService: "https://www.kmart.com.au"
  version: "v1.0"

paths:
  /api/v1/ecovision/packaging:
    get:
      summary: Retrieve resources
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
```

> aws sam template yaml file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  sourcing-ecovision-backend

Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128
    Architectures:
      - x86_64

    Tracing: Active
    Tags:
      stage:
        Ref: StageName
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: '3.0.1'
    TracingEnabled: true

Parameters:
  S3BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the S3 bucket in which the Swagger specification is stored
  StageName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the stage, e.g. "dev", "preprod", "prod"
    Default: dev

Resources:
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: todo-app-api-${StageName}
      StageName:
        Ref: StageName
      DefinitionBody:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "s3://"
                  - Ref: S3BucketName
                  - "/swagger.yaml"

  getAllPackagingMaterialFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/handlers/packaging/
      Handler: packagingHandler.getAllPackagingMaterial
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /api/v1/ecovision/packaging
            Method: GET
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        EntryPoints:
          - src/handlers/packaging/packagingHandler.ts
```

Comment: Can you downgrade your `aws-sam-cli` version to `1.79` and see whether that works?